# rackspace cloudfiles delay before on CDN after upload

Tags: cdn, rackspace, cloudfiles

I am implementing rackspace cloudfiles for a site. If a user uploads a profile image we want to store it on cloudfiles in a CDN enabled container. This works only it takes a couple of secs before the file is available on the CDN.

So when you upload your profile -> we store it in cloud -> reload the page it often isn't available yet resulting in a broken image.

Has anybody experienced this issue and if so how did you work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,this is a function of how CDN's work.

The CDN (in the case of RackSpace, Akamai) must become aware of your content, so it takes some time for your content to show up on a CDN (usually just a matter of minutes).